# Php do not make distinction in if statement with capital letters

Tags: php

I have an `if` statement in my website. And what I want, is that he won't make distinction in capital letters. My `if` statement:

```
<?php
$nameOne = "JOHN";
$check = "john";
if($nameOne == $check){
 echo 'No distinction';
} else {
  echo 'distinction ';
}
?>
```

So, I want to `echo` 'No distinction'.

Comment: @funk No, it isn't a typo. What if `$nameOne` john contains? Then I want to echo "No distinction".

Comment: You were not able to do a simple google search for "php case insensitive string comparison" but ask _here_?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the solution suggested by @NicoHaase

```
<?php
$var1 = "Hello";
$var2 = "hello";
if (strcasecmp($var1, $var2) == 0) {
    echo '$var1 is equal to $var2 in a case-insensitive string comparison';
}
?>
```

https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.strcasecmp.php

Comment: Thanks! I will accepts it about 6 minutes

Answer (score 1):

You can make the comparison using `strtolower()` on both strings

```
if (strtolower($nameOne) == strtolower($check))
```